# How to send messages to logged in users?

Tags: linux

Is there a command that lets me send messages to other logged-in users?
I would like for example to notify users before I shutdown or restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the oldest commands which allows you to send messages to other users is called `write`.

In order for your users to be able to get messages using write, you'll have to enable it (as root).

Running just `mesg` will show you if it's enabled or not.
`mesg y` to enable it.
`mesg n` to disable it.

Then, to send messages:
run `who` to see a list of users who are currently logged into the machine and in the second column you'll find their tty number:

```
[root@centolel ~]# who
root     pts/1        2017-03-15 19:22 (10.13.0.2)
lel      pts/4        2017-03-15 19:30 (10.13.0.2)
```

Then, run:

```
write [user] [tty]
```

And it will let you send messages directly to the user's terminal.

Example:

```
write lel /dev/pts/4
```

Then start typing your message.

Answer (score 3):

`wall` is another alternative, and is used as follows:

`sudo wall 'rebooting in 5 minutes'`

From the man page:

```
NAME
       wall - write a message to all users

SYNOPSIS
       wall [-n] [-t timeout] [message | file]

DESCRIPTION
       wall  displays  a  message, or the contents of a file, or otherwise its standard input, on the terminals of all currently logged in users.
```